# Try to run Usergrid from command-line from jar get NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, apigee, usergrid

I have succesfully finished building the Usergrid. But when I try to run Usergrid from command-line from jar file I got this error:

````
launcher git:(master) java -jar target/usergrid-launcher-*.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/usergrid/launcher/JarMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.usergrid.launcher.JarMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Launcher JAR file are you using?  Try running it without the '*' and using the actual filename.